# number and string during same input

Tags: arrays, c, string

hello ive got this simple program, where i need to imput a number, and 2-letter string, the string is working normally, but the number gets weird

here is the program

```
void main(){
int input_year=0;      
char input_string[1];
        
scanf("%d %s", &input_year, input_string);
char temp1 = input_string[0];
char temp2 = input_string[1];

printf("%d", input_year);
printf("%c", temp1);
printf("%c", temp2);
}
```

input used: `20200405 RD` number (whitespace) String

the temp1 and temp2 are ok, and do what i expect them to do, but the input_year prints 20200192 rather than 20200405.

Comment: so should i make the string array bigger?

Comment: `char input_string[1];` can only hold the *empty string*, and `char temp2 = input_string[1];` is accessing it *out of bounds*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember that strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** strings*. A string of even one single character need space for *two* characters to fit the null-terminator.

Also remember that the size provided in array declarations is the actual number of elements, not the top index. So when you define `input_string` as an array of a single element, that means it only have a single element, with index `0`.

If you want to read a string containing two characters you need to define an array of *three* characters: The two characters in the string plus the null-terminator.

You also need to limit the number of characters that `scanf` will read, so users can't input arbitrarily long strings and cause buffer overflows.

In short:

```
// Place for two characters, plus null-terminator
char input_string[3];

// Limit the input to only two characters (not including null-terminator)
scanf("%d %2s", &input_year, input_string);
```

---

On another note, if you want to use the date input in any other way than a single number, I recommend you read it as separate year, month and day:

```
unsigned year, month, day;
char input_string[3];

scanf("%4u%u%2u %2s", &year, &month, &day, input_string);
```

Also note that I use `unsigned` as a type (and the corresponding `scanf` format) as the input can't and shouldn't be negative.

You should also really check [what `scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value), to make sure the input is valid.

And lastly, to better handle input validation, I recommend you use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read the input into a large string. Then use e.g. `sscanf` (with checking return values) to attempt to parse the input.

Answer (score 2):

Your input buffer is too small

```
char input_string[1];
```

That reserves space for one character. You need 3 in your case of 'rd'. The extra one is because c always adds a 0 at the end of a string. So you need

```
char input_string[3];
```

at least if you are *sure* its always 2 characters

Or maybe

```
char input_string[10];
```

if it could be larger. You can tell `sprintf` the max size you will accept like this (say 2 in your case)

```
scanf("%d %2s", &input_year, input_string);
-----------^
```